# Php exceuter not work?

Tags: wordpress

I use this plugin to execute php code, http://bluesome.net/post/2005/08/18/50/ but it not work my php code not execute.

Answer (score 0):

That plugin hasn't been updated in five years, and WordPress has changed quite a bit since version 2.0. I'd recommend searching in the [WordPress plugin repository](http://wordpress.org/plugins) for something that does the job and is currently maintained. Better yet, learn to create your own plugins and you won't have to rely on a plugin like this anymore.